# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2: 3

Tags: flutter

I am trying to delete pictures from the listView in flutter, randomly choose. Without specifying the location of the image and I get the following error:

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2: 3
```

I don't constantly get it wrong, some times and some not. Depending on choosing the location of the photos.Pictures are deleted from the database.

Here is the code that I used:

```
      child: ListView.builder(
                                                    itemCount: filteredUsers.length,
                                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                                    itemBuilder: (BuildContextcontext, int index) {
                                                      return InkWell(
                                                        child: Padding(
                                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0, left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                                                            child:
                                                            Container(
                                                                height: 140, width: 140,
                                                                child:
                                                                ClipRRect(
                                                                  borderRadius:
                                                                  BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                                                  child:
                                                                  AspectRatio(
                                                                    aspectRatio:
                                                                    1.2,
                                                                    child:
                                                                    Image.network(
                                                                      filteredUsers[index].ImageURL.toString(),
                                                                      width: double.infinity,
                                                                      height: 400,
                                                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                                    ),

                                                                  ),
                                                                ))),

                                                          onTap: () {
                                                            showDialog(
                                                              context: context,
                                                              builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
                                                                //   title: Text("Alert Dialog Box"),
                                                                content: Text("delete..?".tr()),
                                                                actions: <Widget>[
                                                                  TextButton(
                                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                                      setState(
                                                                              () {
                                                                            filteredUsers
                                                                                .removeAt(
                                                                                index);
                                                                            deleteImage(filteredUsers[index].id);
                                                                            Navigator.of(ctx).pop();

                                                                          });

                                                                    },

                                                                    child: Text("OKdelete".tr()),
                                                                  ),
                                                                  TextButton(
                                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                                      Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                                                                    },

                                                                    child: Text("Closes".tr()),
                                                                  ),
                                                                ],
                                                              ),
                                                            );



                                                          }
                                                      );
                                                    },
                                                  ),
```

```
  void deleteImage(id) {
    var url = "https://***************deleteImage.php";
    http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
      'id': id.toString(),
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happening because you are removing first and then accessing it again while doing this

```
filteredUsers.removeAt(index);
deleteImage(filteredUsers[index].id);
```

But, by the time the first statement completes, `filteredUsers[index]` will be null and then you can't access `null.id`.

Change your code to this,

```
var id = filteredUsers[index].id;      // First get the id from the item
filteredUsers.removeAt(index);         // Then you can delete it
deleteImage(id);                       // Use the new id variable you just created
```